# Optimization on slow query that employs join and where clause

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I have below query that takes approx 1 Minute to run and expected result in less then 5 second

```
SELECT COUNT(1) as total,
       FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tr.created_at)/(30 * 60)) AS _time,
       CAST(MIN(tr.created_at) AS CHAR) as created_at,
       AVG(case when tr.reached =0 then null else trd.nd_value end) as nd_value
FROM read tr 
JOIN readdetails as trd ON (tr.id=trd.trailerread_id)
WHERE tr.trailer_id=7 
  AND trd.traileroidtype_id=11
  AND tr.created_at between DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -365 DAY) 
  AND now()
GROUP BY _time
ORDER BY _time;
```

**Here detail of tables which are used in this query **

**his table has 220111 rows**

```
CREATE TABLE `read` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `trailer_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `trailerrisk_id` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finished` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `hasdata` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `reached` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `lastlog_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `trailerreads_trailercreateat_idx` (`trailer_id`,`created_at`),
  KEY `ind_trailerreads_finish` (`finished`),
  CONSTRAINT `trailerreads_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`trailer_id`) REFERENCES `trailers` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=227510 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

**This table has 1767873 rows**

```
CREATE TABLE `readdetails` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `trailerread_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `traileroidtype_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `range_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trailerrisk_id` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nd_value` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `trailerread_id` (`trailerread_id`),
  KEY `traileroidtype_id` (`traileroidtype_id`),
  KEY `trailerrisk_id` (`trailerrisk_id`),
  KEY `range_id` (`range_id`),
  KEY `trailer_value` (`nd_value`),
  KEY `trailerreaddetails_idx_traileroidtype_id` (`traileroidtype_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `trailerreaddetails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`trailerread_id`) REFERENCES `trailerreads` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `trailerreaddetails_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`traileroidtype_id`) REFERENCES `traileroidtypes` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `trailerreaddetails_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`trailerrisk_id`) REFERENCES `trailerrisks` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1840745 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

I have tried with changes indexing and also try combination of where clause

Comment: You have condition `... tr.trailer_id=7 and trd.traileroidtype_id=11 and tr.created_at between DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -365 DAY) ...`  But you have a composite index `KEY trailerreads_trailercreateat_idx (trailer_id,created_at)`, so that might not be used. Did you try creating an index only on trailer_id? Or try putting indexed 2 fields first `... tr.trailer_id=7 and tr.created_at between DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -365 DAY) and trd.traileroidtype_id=11 ...`, and since it is BETWEEN, not sure if it would be used, but still try

Comment: Also, `tr.created_at between DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -365 DAY) AND NOW()` can be changed to just `tr.created_at >= DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -365 DAY)`. `created_at` would not be a future date-time, right?

Comment: Can you update your post with the definition of indices and the output of the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` command, when executed on your query?

Comment: Aggregating by `FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tr.created_at)/(30 * 60))` is killing performance. Maybe you can precompute and index that expression in advance...

Comment: I would create both of the following indexes, and then I would find out which one the engine uses: `create index ix1 on read (trailer_id, created_at, (FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tr.created_at)/(30 * 60))));` and `create index ix2 on read (trailer_id, (FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tr.created_at)/(30 * 60))), created_at);`

Comment: @Ishan thank you i have created index   KEY `idx_trailer_id` (`trailer_id`)

 and execute below query with only counts

   select     
        count(1)
                from trailerreads  tr 
    join  trailerreaddetails as trd on (tr.id=trd.trailerread_id )
    where
    tr.trailer_id=7 and trd.traileroidtype_id=11
                and tr.created_at >= DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -50 DAY)  

it takes around 1 Min

Comment: Hmm..  So, neither a new index just on `trainer_id` nor the elimination of `FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tr.created_at)/(30 * 60))` helped. Can you pl. also add `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output of the SELECT query as @lemon suggested.

Comment: Usage of index highly depends also on the cardinality of the index. If for `trailer_id = 7`, there will be too many records that MySQL will think going through the table sequentially will be much faster as compared to going through index and then going through MOST of the records, then it wouldn't use the index.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM read WHERE trailer_id = 7`, and `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM readdetails WHERE trailerread_id = 7`, and `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM readdetails WHERE trailerread_id = 7 AND traileroidtype_id = 11`. Give output of these too. Also, do these individually take time too?